# populate a collection select from available locales rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I would like users to be able to select the interface language but I want this to get populated from the available locales like the following.

[image]

here is what I have in the form.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :locale %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :locale, :translated_locale, I18n.avilable_locales, :translated_locale %>
    </div>
```

and here is the `translated_locale` method in `User` model

```
 def translated_locale
    I18n.t(locale)
  end
```

Comment: Please post the related code.

Comment: post updated with code

Comment: Ok. What does the dropdown currently show?

Comment: yeah but not like the image which i am trying to achieve

Comment: You had typo: `I18n.avilable_locales` should be `I18n.available_locales`